# Particles render much larger than in viewport

Tags: particles

Particles are big and round. The scale is right, the size and the speed, it's suppose to be like this:

[image]

Even when I try to change the scale, it doesn't do anything. They are supposed to look smaller

[image]

Here are the setting it's using:
[image]

Comment: Here, I edited it back

Comment: There is probably a discrepancy in how size settings for "vieport display" section and "render" section.

Comment: OMG Yes! Thank you so much, Ive spend the entire day trying to figure it out!

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so that other users with a similar question can learn from your experience. Read:

[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the size of my particles in "Viewport display" section and "render" had to be the same.